# How to use babel-standalone to transpile ES6 javascript that uses the spread/rest operator?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next, spread-syntax

I need to make my javascript (which is in a non-Node.js environment) backwards compatible so I'm trying to utilize Babel to transpile my code as suggested in this [post](https://hackernoon.com/polyfills-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-or-maybe-a-bit-less-7c8de164e423)

[babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone) works great except it doesnt seem to work with the spread/rest operator

For example, the following works great:

```
var input = 'const getMessage = (D) => {return D}';
var output = Babel.transform(input, { presets: ['es2015'] }).code;
```

However, the following generates an error:

```
var input = 'const getMessage = (D) => {...D}';
var output = Babel.transform(input, { presets: ['es2015'] }).code;
```

Error Below

```
babel.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (1:26)
> 1 | const getMessage = (D) => return {D}
    |                           ^
babel.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (1:27)
> 1 | const getMessage = (D) => {...D}
    |                            ^
    at t.J.raise (babel.min.js:7)
    at t.X.unexpected (babel.min.js:5)
    at te.parseExprAtom (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseExprSubscripts (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseMaybeUnary (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseExprOps (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseMaybeConditional (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseMaybeAssign (babel.min.js:6)
    at te.parseExpression (babel.min.js:6)
    at t.z.parseStatement (babel.min.js:5)
babel.js:14449 Uncaught SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (1:27)
> 1 | const getMessage = (D) => {...D}
    |                            ^
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (babel.js:14449)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (babel.js:11756)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (babel.js:13745)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (babel.js:13489)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (babel.js:13469)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (babel.js:13399)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (babel.js:13376)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (babel.js:13339)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (babel.js:13301)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (babel.js:11901)
```

[See my codepen here](https://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/NZBgMd?editors=1011)

The babel-standalone github page states "It's bundled with all the standard Babel plugins and presets," yet it cant seem to transpile my usage of the spread operator

Comment: Not a bebel expert, but here's one thing I noticed. `{}` after an arrow function is treated as a function block, not as an implicit return of an object. So your first example is really just creating a function with doesn't return anything. So trying to spread into a function block `{...D}` will give an error. To return an object encase the object in parentheses  `const getMessage = (D) => ({...D})` <--- valid syntax

Comment: and `(D) => return {D}` should be `(D) => {return D}`

Comment: Can you show us your babel configuration, please? Notice that object rest/spread syntax is not part of ES6.

Comment: According to the Babel Standalone documentation, "config files don't work in @babel/standalone, as no file system access is available. The presets and/or plugins to use must be specified in the options passed to Babel.transform."  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone